# Поиск слов с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как составить регулярное выражение на поиск слов(а) в тексте при условии, что данное слово появляется более n-раз.

> Пример.
>
> Ищем слово 'world', которое встречается ровно 3 и более раза

1. Hello my world
2. Hello my world, hello my world, hello my world

Регулярка не должна находить соответствие в первом тексте, но во втором найдет все 3  и более слова.

Comment: php? javascript?

Comment: А ведь минусующие возможно не поняли вопроса. Нужно найти только повторяющиеся слова, а не все.

Comment: Поиском пользовался и ничего не добился.

Comment: Нужно именно повторы найти, мне не надо все найти, а только то, что повторяется и определенное кол-во раз. Язык PHP,Java, JS. Мне желательно чистый RegEx без привязки к конкретному языку программирования

Comment: @lolokot, что-то мне подсказывает, что проще и правильнее отобрать все вхождения подстроки и оценить их количество в программном коде.

Comment: могу на Java предложить вариант такой регулярки, если интересно

Comment: Кажется вот то, что Вам нужно: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333681/regex-repeated-words-on-the-same-line

Comment: @Александр если Вам не сложно, то предоставьте данный код

Comment: @DmitriySimushev это да, но проблема в том, что вероятность внедрения кода меньше чем регулярки

Comment: Считаю, что решить задачу чистой регуляркой невозможно. Код на языке применения все равно нужен для обработки результата.

Comment: @Visman чистой регуляркой уже сделали, осталось понять как работает. Пример у DmitriySimushev

Comment: @lolokot, вы ошибаетесь. Разве та регулярка вам вернула все вхождения слова?

Comment: @Visman как я понимаю, то не все. Она ищет все вхождения, которые не включены в лимит,т.е. задаю {1,} он найдет все слова кроме 1 и так далее.

Comment: @lolokot, эта регулярка не выполняет того, что вы сформулировали в своем вопросе. Пока я остаюсь при своем мнении: чистой регуляркой нельзя вернуть все вхождения слова в предложение, если оно встречается там более n раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать вот такой вариант (на основе [на основе этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333681/regex-repeated-words-on-the-same-line)):

```
/(\b\w+\b)(?=(?:.*?\b\1\b){2,})/ig
```

Пример: https://regex101.com/r/cS2sH3/1

Сразу обращаю внимание, что если вхождений больше трех, то слово будет выбрано **несколько раз** (количество вхождений минус 2).

Несколько пояснений о том, как работает это регулярное выражение:

1. `(\b\w+\b)` маска захватывает "слово". При этом, символы `\b` обозначают границу слова и не захватываются маской.
2. `\1` используется для ссылки на найденную последовательность символов.
3. `.*?\b\1\b` следует читать как "ранее найденное слово, которому предшествует один или более произвольных символов".
4. `(?: ... ){2,}` определяется группа символов, которая повоторяется 2 или более раз. При этом используется незахватывающая маска `(?:)`
5. Группа `abc(?=def)` проверяет, следует ли указанная группа символов за `def` за символами `abc`, не сдвигая при этом текущую позицию в строке.

Ну и в целом, есть у меня такое чувство, что при решении задачи лучше использовать не только регулярное выражение, но и программный код.

Comment: Если использовать программный код, то данный вопрос не появился тут. Дело в том, что данная регулярка подставляет как шаблон поиск в программу. Хотя можно ее переписать, но это займет некоторое время. Я не много не понимаю как работает Ваша регулярка. Можете по шагам разъяснить?

Comment: @lolokot, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 1):

**UPD**

Я бы просто пользовался обратными ссылками:

```
^.*(world)(.*(\1)){2}.*$
                   ^ n-1 раз повторений
```

Пример: https://regex101.com/r/zK2hG2/3

Comment: Угу. А если ему надо найти вхождение слова более 2 раз, например, а вхождений слова в предложение 5?

Comment: Согласен, поспешил. Обновил.

Comment: Да проблема не в этом, а вот в чем -> `все 3 и более слова` То есть по вопросу получается, что регулярка должна вернуть столько групп сколько искомых слов есть в предложении, если количество вхождений слова больше `n`. P.S. Думаю чистой регуляркой это не решить.

Comment: Либо текст вопроса сформирован не верно :)

Comment: Зачем ставить начало и конец строки, если рядом `.*`?

Comment: Данная регулярка всю строку ищет) А нужно лишь конкретное кол-во слов в строке.

Comment: Задача - найти слово: "Ищем слово 'world'..." то есть надо найти слово. Искомое слово будет в первой группе. Про `^` и `$` можно и не ставить, ошибся. @Visman @Qwertiy @lolokot

Comment: @streetturtle но находит все строку судя по ссылке из вашего примера

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log([
"Hello my world",
"Hello my world, hello my world, hello my world",
"Hell hello he",
"123 1234 2345 3456 666 999 000 123",
"123 1234 2345 3456 123 666 999 123 000 123",].map(function(s) {
  var match = s.match(/\b(\w+)\b(?=(.*?\b\1\b){2})/gi);
  return match ? match.join(" ") : "";
}).join("\n"))
```

Вывод:

```
Hello my world


123 123
```

Чтобы слово находилось только один раз:

```
console.log([
"Hello my world",
"Hello my world, hello my world, hello my world",
"Hell hello he",
"123 1234 2345 3456 666 999 000 123",
"123 1234 2345 3456 123 666 999 000 123 123",].map(function(s) {
  var match = s.match(/\b(\w+)\b(?=(((?!\b\1\b).)*?\b\1\b){2}((?!\b\1\b).)*$)/gi);
  return match ? match.join(" ") : "";
}).join("\n"))
```

Вывод:

```
Hello my world


123
```

Comment: А чем ваша регулярка принципиально отличается от той, что у меня в ответе? ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev 1. Я твой ответ не видел - у нас всего 2 минуты разница. 2. У тебя "или более" лишнее в "2 или более". 3. Сейчас исправлю, чтобы слово только один раз находилось.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, дополнил.

Comment: 2 минуты это существенно ;) А если серьезно, то в вопросе нет указания на язык программирования. Более того, автор в комментариях указывает на необходимость решения без программного кода, а раз так, то ваш ответ по-сути идентичен моему.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, но тестить регулярку как-то надо было. В любом случае, с того момента, как я добавил ещё одну регулярку, находящую каждое слово ровно один раз, ответ уж точно стал не идентичен.

Answer (score 0):

По примеру, ищем `world` в строке `Hello my world, hello my world, hello my world`.

Регулярное выражение на `java` будет иметь вид:

`private final string REGEX = .+(world)+.{3,}`

**Объяснение:**
 `.+` предполагает, что перед словом `world` могут быть любые символы либо другие слова.
`+.` предполагает, что после слова `world` так же могут быть другие символы или слова.
`{3,}` означает последовательность минимум из 3-х символов `X`, а  `X` = `world`

**P.S.: Если что-то не так, поправьте меня.**